Execution failed for task ':app:processDevDebugResources'
Our project needs to update the Android API Level from 33 to 34 but I get this error after updating the version.
Error logs:

A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask$TaskAction
AAPT2 aapt2-7.0.0-7396180-windows Daemon #1: Unexpected error during link, attempting to stop daemon.

These are the versions of our project:
Gradle JDK : oracle openjdk 14.0.2
Android Gradle Plugin (AGP) : 7.0.0
Gradle Version : 7.1.1
Kotlin version : 1.5.21
I tried updating the gradle heap size from org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m to 4g but not working.

Is this a KMP project? Is it possible you are applying the Android plugin to a common/shared subproject, similar to this jetbrains issue?
If that doesn't help perhaps you need to clear caches.
Command-line: rm ~/.gradle/caches
In Android Studio: Invalidate Caches
